# Count days between two date - J2ME

Tags: java, java-me

I want to count days between two date, I found some solutions on the net but the problem is in my NetBeans the **GregorianCalendar** is not available. So cant calculate the days. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java Micro Edition you don't have GregorianCalendar, so you have to use:

```
Date startDate, endDate;
...
int days = (int) ((endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime())  
    / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

Where the getTime() method of a Date `returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT`