# Java ME - how to get number of days in month

Tags: java-me, calendar

The Java ME [java.util.Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/util/Calendar.html) class does not have the `getActualMaximum()` method:

> ...This class has been subset for J2ME based on the JDK 1.3 Calendar class. Many methods and variables have been pruned, and other methods simplified, in an effort to reduce the size of this class.

Is it even possible to get number of days in month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work using the answer below. 
But thanks to Nate for giving a working example.

```
public static int getMaxDaysInMonth(int month, int year){
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month+1);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cal.get(Calendar.DATE)-1);

    return cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
}
```

It seems to be the shortest and also seems to work fine. Any comments?

Answer (score 3):

In J2ME, since you don't have `Calendar.getActualMaximum()` available, you could try something like the following: using the [calculation from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7708923/119114), you could calculate the number of days between the 1st day of the month you're interested in, and the 1st day of the next month.

```
   private int getDaysInMonth(int month, int year) {
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  // or pick another time zone if necessary
      cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
      cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);      // 1st day of month
      cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
      cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
      cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
      Date startDate = cal.getTime();

      int nextMonth = (month == Calendar.DECEMBER) ? Calendar.JANUARY : month + 1;
      cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, nextMonth);
      if (month == Calendar.DECEMBER) {
         cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year + 1);
      }
      Date endDate = cal.getTime();

      // get the number of days by measuring the time between the first of this
      //   month, and the first of next month
      return (int)((endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
   }
```

Note that this method takes months as `Calendar` constants, like `Calendar.JANUARY`. I think the raw integer representation of those is 0-indexed, so if you pass `12` for December, the results may be wrong.  I also haven't tested daylight savings time issues, so you'll have to verify that this is sufficient for your app's needs.

Use the above function like so:

```
  int d = getDaysInMonth(Calendar.DECEMBER, 2012);
  d = getDaysInMonth(Calendar.FEBRUARY, 2012);
  d = getDaysInMonth(Calendar.FEBRUARY, 2013);
```

which will yield d =

```
31
29
28
```

(for US time zones).

Comment: I think i found a shorter version of your method (see my update), but it was the first answer that used java ME API.

Comment: @Pma, Yep, your answer seems cleaner.  One comment, though.  There is a logic flaw, that probably doesn't actually hurt you.  If you ask for the number of days in December 2012, for example, it gives you the number of days in December 2011. That probably can't ever fail, since December isn't a month that changes numbers of days ... I just thought I'd mention it.  You can consider that an optimization :)

Answer (score -1):

Use the [getActualMaximum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMaximum%28int%29) method on `Calendar`

> Returns the maximum value that the specified calendar field could
>   have, given the time value of this Calendar. For example, the actual
>   maximum value of the MONTH field is 12 in some years, and 13 in other
>   years in the Hebrew calendar system.

[Example from RoseIndia](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-get-example/number-days-month.shtml):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = 2008;
int month = Calendar.FEBRUARY;
int date = 1;
calendar.set(year, month, date);
int days = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
System.out.println("Number of Days: " + days);
```

Comment: @Pma Any luck or questions?

Comment: `getActualMaximum` method is referred from Java SE api docs (`http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/blah blah`). Java SE is a different platform than Java Me and ME API is much limited compared to SE